# No module named 'django_auth_ldap'

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm trying to configure a website with django and LDAP authentification. Upon my login page, I just type in any username and password, and expect to get to a different html page (without connecting to a database, for now. My method in my view.py file:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        print ('*'*50)
        print (request.POST)
        print ('*'*50)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print ('*'*50)
        print (user)
        print ('*'*50)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "User is not active in Database") 
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please check your username and password!")
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

I'm new to django so not even too sure whether I should be seeing any page of if this error message is correct. I'm using Python3.5 and I installed successfully pyasn1-0.2.3. Then going into my console I can successfully `import ldap3`. However I can't get any further than this.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'UserAuth',
]
```

Any my directory looks like this:

```
UserAuth
  -> user_auth
  -> UserAuth
  manage.py
```

From what I can deduce, it appears that django_ldap_auth cannot be easily installed for 1. Windows 8.1 Enterprise and 2. for Python 3 (https://github.com/susundberg/django-auth-ldap-ad)

That is annoying, perhaps if I switch to Python2 maybe this would work....

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: pip install django-auth-ldap use this

Comment: @Exprator: ImportError at /login/
No module named 'django_auth_ldap'. When I use the "pip install django-auth-ldap" command I get a "No matching distribution found for django-auth-ldap" error message.

Comment: post your settings file

Comment: and did you install pyldap?

Comment: For the installation of pyldap I used: ldap3-2.2.4.win-amd64.exe

Comment: post your setting files

Comment: pip install ldap3 and check once

Comment: Ok the pip worked, because then "import ldap3'" came back with no errors.

Comment: and have you used ldap backend in the settings file? it wont work unless you use that

Comment: You mean: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

Comment: I downloaded the file: "django_auth_ldap-1.2.8-py3-none-any.whl" then did pip install on this file when saved to my desktop. The message came back as "Requirement already satisfied", then "Collecting pyldap" but "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyldap (from django-auth-ldap==1.2.8)

Comment: you dont need that userauth in the installed apps if you are usign ldap. https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/ go through this and follow the steps

Comment: I don't want to use the live (production) ldap server for the moment. I have instead an ldap.sh script, and for the moment just want to get it up and running.

Comment: For the moment I commented out the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in my settings.py file, and now my page gets redirected. But at a later stage this will need to be added for testing against the LDAP server (in production), so problem NOT solved.

Comment: It seems that installing on my Mac and MBP were very straight forward ("pip install python-ldap" and "pip-install django-auth-ldap"), but I get a connection timeout error when using the Windows PC...could be a proxy setting issue at my work that may need sorting first.

Comment: From what I can deduce, it appears that django_ldap_auth cannot be easily installed for 1. Windows 8.1 Enterprise and 2. for Python 3 (https://github.com/susundberg/django-auth-ldap-ad)
That is annoying, perhaps if I switch to Python2 maybe this would work....

Answer (score 0):

I reached a dead with this and unless I hear on the contrary, then for Python3 users on Windows, this will also become a dead end. A thread on the matter can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-auth-ldap/T80u61-ZM5k).

Instead I'll now try with Radius.